# Display images in Horizontal Gridview using single row

Tags: android

I want to display images in horizontal Gridview in single row on top of the screen. It should have multiple images and should scroll accordingly when the images is focused. The focused images should be positioned at center of the screen.

Thanks

Main_activity.xml******

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >

<android.support.v17.leanback.widget.HorizontalGridView
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/horview"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
     >
<!--
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/_image"/>-->

</android.support.v17.leanback.widget.HorizontalGridView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Main activity.java****

```
package com.example.farhanm.horizontal2;

import android.support.v17.leanback.widget.HorizontalGridView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private View hview;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private HorizontalGridView hgview;
    private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    private int[] images = {R.color.colorAccent, R.color.colorPrimary, R.color.colorPrimaryDark, R.color.lb_action_text_color,
            R.color.lb_basic_card_bg_color, R.color.colorAccent};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       // relativeLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relative1);
        hgview=(HorizontalGridView)findViewById(R.id.horview);
       for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {


           hview =getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.hview, null);
            imageView = (ImageView)hview.findViewById(R.id._image);
            imageView.setImageResource(images[i]);
          //  relativeLayout.addView(imageView);
            hgview.addView(imageView);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: show us your efforts, post your code and tell what you have tried

Comment: i am new to this technology.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this one, you can try below code

```
<android.support.v17.leanback.widget.HorizontalGridView
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/horview"
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">
```

Add  `RecyclerView` into a `Linearlayout` in your XML:

```
<LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/image_LAY"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
          android:id="@+id/recycler_view_image"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:padding="3dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Use `LinearLayoutmanager` and set its orientation to `horizontal`

```
final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(myContext);
layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
ImageRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Create an `RecyclerView` adapter to add images horizontally. And add Array of images to `Recyclerview` Adapter.

```
 RecyclerViewAdapter = new STOffsiteRVAdapter(aImageInfos, Context);
 ImageRecyclerView.setAdapter(RecyclerViewAdapter);
```

Comment: Thanks. But the requirement is to use horizontalgridview